# URL Rewrite backwards

Tags: php, url-rewriting

Is there any possibility of URL rewrite working in a backward way.

Usually rewrite URLs in this way,

`http://somedomain.com/something` for `http://somedomain.com/something.php`

But if I try for `^something.php ./something [NC,L]` I get an error 'Server Error'

How can I implement this?

Comment: are you tring to rewrite http://somedomain.com/something => http://somedomain.com/something.php ? since you said you want it backwards?

Comment: No somedomain.com/something.php to somedomain.com/something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Second parameter to the RewriteRule cannot have a `./`, it must be absolute. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^something\.php$ /something [NC,L]
```